# Unable to find headers with make

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a (fairly simple) makefile adapted from [here](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/) that I am attempting to use to build a project on Ubuntu.  The project tree is fairly simple: Makefile is in the root project directory, and there are `src/`, `include/`, `build/`, and `bin/`, where source code, header files, object files, and executables are stored, respectively.

When I run `make` from the root directory of the project, I get the following error message:

```
Linking...
g++                  src/Main.cpp src/Foo.cpp -o bin/runner     
src/Main.cpp:1:19: fatal error: Foo.hpp: No such file or directory 
#include "Foo.hpp"
               ^
compilation terminated.
src/Foo.cpp:1:19: fatal error: Foo.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "Foo.hpp"
               ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [bin/runner] Error 1
```

All that's currently in the project is `Main.cpp`. which calls two test functions `Foo()` and `Bar()` from `Foo.cpp`, which references a header file `Foo.hpp`.  Here is the makefile:

```
CC := g++               # This is the main compiler
SRCDIR := src           # Directory for source code
BUILDDIR := build       # Directory containing all object files, which are removed on "make clean"
TARGET := bin/runner    # bin/runner contains the main executable for project
                        # bin/ contains all other executables in the project (such as tests)

SRCEXT := cpp           # File extension of source code

# Look for all the source files in SRCDIR with the file extension specified above
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))

# Name all object files the same root name as the source files from which they came, but add a .o extension to the end
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))

# The -g flag specifies that debugging information should be produced in the native format of the OS
CFLAGS := -g -Wall

# Various flags for libraries that might need to be linked
INC := -I include       # Ensures that all header files (in the include/ folder) are accessible for build

# Show the components that are currently being compiled/linked
# Also, this is the main procedure for make: The TARGET is built from the objects, and
# object files are built from source
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo " Linking..."
    @echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    @echo " $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

# Directives for "make clean" which cleans all object files out of the build/ folder
clean:
    @echo " Cleaning..."; 
    @echo " $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

# Destroys everything in the build/ and bin/runner/ folders. Does not clean test executables.
.PHONY: clean
```

What am I missing here in order to get the header files to be properly linked?

EDIT:  Here is the new makefile, and the current output:

```
# This is the main compiler
CC := g++

# Directory for source code
SRCDIR := src

# Directory containing all object files, which are removed on "make clean"
BUILDDIR := build

# bin/runner contains the main executable for project
# bin/ contains all other executables in the project (such as tests)
TARGET := bin/runner

# File extension of source code
SRCEXT := cpp

# Ensures that all header files (in the include/ folder) are accessible for build
INC := -I/include

# Look for all the source files in SRCDIR with the file extension specified above
# SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.$(SRCEXT))

# Name all object files the same root name as the source files from which they came, but add a .o extension to the end
# OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(TARGET)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))

# The -g flag specifies that debugging information should be produced in the native format of the OS
CFLAGS := -g -Wall

# Various flags for libraries that might need to be linked
LIB := #-pthread -lmongoclient -L lib -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt

# Show the components that are currently being compiled/linked
# Also, this is the main procedure for make: The TARGET is built from the objects, and
# object files are built from source
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo " Linking..."
    $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET)
    # @echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

# Directives for "make clean" which cleans all object files out of the build/ folder
clean:
    @echo " Cleaning..."; 
    @echo " $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

# Tests
# tester:
    # $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test/tester.cpp $(INC) $(LIB) -o bin/tester

# Spikes
# ticket:
    # $(CC) $(CFLAGS) spikes/ticket.cpp $(INC) $(LIB) -o bin/ticket

# Destroys everything in the build/ and bin/runner/ folders. Does not clean test executables.
.PHONY: clean
```

Output:

```
[scott]> make
make: *** No rule to make target `bin/runner/Foo.o', needed by `bin/runner'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Your second error is completely different than the first; you should open a new question.  However, it's happening because you wrote `OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(TARGET)/ ...` when you meant to write `OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/ ...`

Comment: @MadScientist I asked him to update for the second question.I thought about suggesting to open a new question but it seemed "related" enough and the solution to the first problem didn't seem "complete" enough (in that it didn't really advance the OP in any real way towards his goal.

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr

Don't put end-of-line comments on variable assignments in make. It doesn't work the way you might expect.

---

#### Explanation

Your makefile isn't running the steps you expect it is.

You shouldn't be seeing `Linking...` for the compilation step.

make shouldn't be attempting to create the target from the source `.cpp` files.

You *should* be seeing your `INC` and `CFLAGS` values on the compilation line (but you are getting linking output so obviously aren't seeing them).

That's why your header can't be found by the way, your linking line doesn't have `-I` on it anywhere.

The reason that's happening is because make is applying the wrong rule.

make is applying the wrong rule because your variables are being set incorrectly.

Your variables are being set incorrectly because your variables have values you don't expect.

The makefile you started from had errors the author wasn't aware of.

make is not always very smart.

When you write

```
FOO := some value     # comment
```

you expect `FOO` to have the value `some value` but make sees things differently.

make gives it the value `some value` since it can't tell the difference between the space between `some` and `value` and the space after `value` and before the comment.

So when you run your shell command (with `*.$(SRCEXT)` unquoted) the shell just ignores the trailing spaces). (Try quoting `*.'$(SRCEXT)'` and see what you get.)

However when you then try to `$(SOURCES:=.$(SRCEXT)=.o)` make doesn't drop the spaces and you have actually written `$(src/Main.cpp src/Foo.cpp:=cpp           =.o)` which, you may notice, is a pattern that doesn't actually match.

As a result `$(OBJECTS)` gets the unmodified value of `$(SOURCES)` and "confuses" the `$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)` line later causing make to skip your compilation target.

(Oh, also, that's why your linking line has a million spaces between `g++` and the first source file.)

Oh, also, you don't need to shell out for find there unless your `src/` directory has sub-directories of its own (and even then not with some make magic) because `$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.$(SRCEXT))` will work just fine (and also would have failed earlier I believe given this problem).

Comment: I changed the source-finding statement to `SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.$(SRCEXT))`, removed all trailing comments (so that there are no lines with both comments and executable code), and changed the compilation block to `@echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(INC)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(INC)`.  I'm still getting the same error as before, though.  Did I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: @Scott The original compilation target looked fine to me (a bit verbose since make by default echos the command it is running so you don't need to manually echo it and silence the normal echo but whatever). You shouldn't have needed to change that. `-I` might be positional, keep it before the source files. Also update your post with the new makefile contents and the new output from `make`.

Answer (score 1):

Define an environment variable that has . (current working directory) first, then ./include (not just include subdirectory but as ,/include and rest of the INCLUDE dirs that you might already have because of the compiler or other software requirement)

```
set INCLUDE :=.:./include:$INCLUDE
```

Alternately, use:

```
INC := -I. -I./include
```

gcc -I option is as: -I dir
Adds the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files. Directories named by '-I' are searched before the standard system include directories. If the directory dir is a standard system include directory, the option is ignored to ensure that the default search order for system directories and the special treatment of system headers are not defeated